# Post image to blobstore on local development server

Tags: android, google-app-engine, android-studio, blobstore

I tried to post image from android client to blobstore on local development server(Android Studio 1.0.2), but got the following error on local server:

```
req == null? : false
req size : 7680130
ihimage
blobs is null? : false
blobs empty: true
blobs size: 0
blobKeys is null? : true
ก.พ. 02, 2558 10:37:57 ก่อนเที่ยง com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger warn
WARNING: /_ah/upload/ag9teUFwcGxpY2F0aW9uSWRyIgsSFV9fQmxvYlVwbG9hZFNlc3Npb25fXxiAgICAgICACgw
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at net.xxx.UloadServlet.doPost(UloadServlet.java:53)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:63)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:366)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectModuleRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:349)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:116)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:98)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:327)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:126)
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.UploadBlobServlet.handleUpload(UploadBlobServlet.java:432)
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.UploadBlobServlet.access$000(UploadBlobServlet.java:71)
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.UploadBlobServlet$1.run(UploadBlobServlet.java:117)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.UploadBlobServlet.doPost(UploadBlobServlet.java:114)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:127)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:63)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:125)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:366)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectModuleRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:349)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:116)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:98)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:491)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:938)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:755)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)

ก.พ. 02, 2558 10:37:57 ก่อนเที่ยง com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger warn
WARNING: Error for /_ah/api/postApi/v1/post
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/appengine/repackaged/org/codehaus/jackson/node/ObjectNode
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2532)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2842)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:345)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Holder.newInstance(Holder.java:153)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:428)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.getServlet(ServletHolder.java:339)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:487)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:127)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:63)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:125)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:366)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectModuleRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:349)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:116)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:98)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:491)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:938)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:755)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.codehaus.jackson.node.ObjectNode
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.IsolatedAppClassLoader.loadClass(IsolatedAppClassLoader.java:216)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 42 more

ก.พ. 02, 2558 10:38:03 ก่อนเที่ยง com.google.appengine.api.datastore.dev.LocalDatastoreService$PersistDatastore persist
INFO: Time to persist datastore: 58 ms
ก.พ. 02, 2558 10:38:42 ก่อนเที่ยง com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger info
INFO: org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectorManager$SelectSet@599cf3f6 JVM BUG(s) - injecting delay3 times
ก.พ. 02, 2558 10:38:42 ก่อนเที่ยง com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger info
INFO: org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectorManager$SelectSet@599cf3f6 JVM BUG(s) - recreating selector 3 times, canceled keys 122 times
```

this is servlet code on server

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws IOException {
    System.out.println("req == null? : "+(req==null));
    System.out.println("req size : "+req.getContentLength());
    for (Enumeration<String> e = req.getParameterNames(); e.hasMoreElements();)
        System.out.println(e.nextElement());
    Map<String, List<BlobKey>> blobs = bstoreservice.getUploads(req);
    System.out.println("blobs is null? : " + (blobs == null));
    if (blobs!= null){
        System.out.println("blobs empty: "+blobs.isEmpty());
        System.out.println("blobs size: " + blobs.size());
    }
    List<BlobKey> blobKeys = blobs.get("ihimage");
    System.out.println("blobKeys is null? : " + (blobKeys == null));
    if (blobKeys!=null)
        System.out.println("blobKeys size : "+blobKeys.size());
    BlobKey blobKey = blobKeys.get(0);

    ImagesService imagesService = ImagesServiceFactory.getImagesService();
    ServingUrlOptions servingOptions = ServingUrlOptions.Builder.withBlobKey(blobKey);

    String servingUrl = imagesService.getServingUrl(servingOptions);

    resp.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
    resp.setContentType("application/json");

    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
    json.put("servingUrl", servingUrl);
    json.put("blobKey", blobKey.getKeyString());

    PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
    out.print(json.toString());
    out.flush();
    out.close();
}
```

and this is client side code

```
private void doNewPost() {
    getUrlTask gurlTask = new getUrlTask();
    String[] tmp = new String[1];
    tmp[0] = "http://"+SERV_ADDR+":8080/blob/getuplurl";
    gurlTask.execute(tmp);
}

class getUrlTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String url = params[0];
        HttpClient hclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(hclient.getParams(), 10000);
        HttpGet hget = new HttpGet(url);
        String respStr = null;
        try {
            HttpResponse resp = hclient.execute(hget);
            respStr = new BasicResponseHandler().handleResponse(resp);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //return null;
        return respStr;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        doUpload(s);
    }

}

private void doUpload(String uloadurl) {
    UploadTask uploadTask = new UploadTask();
    //bitmap to byte array conversion
    int bytes = bitmap.getRowBytes()*bitmap.getHeight();
    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(bytes); //Create a new buffer
    bitmap.copyPixelsToBuffer(buffer); //Move the byte data to the buffer
    byte[] array = buffer.array(); 

    Object[] tmp = new Object[2];
    tmp[0] = uloadurl;
    tmp[1] = array;
    uploadTask.execute(tmp);
}

class UploadTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, String>{
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Object[] objects) {
        String ulurl = (String) objects[0];
        byte[] bytimg = (byte[]) objects[1];

        if (ulurl == null) return null;
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(ulurl);

        MultipartEntityBuilder entityBuilder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
        entityBuilder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

        entityBuilder.addBinaryBody("ihimage", bytimg);
        HttpEntity entity = entityBuilder.build();
        httppost.setEntity(entity);
        HttpResponse response = null;
        try {
            response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //storeData(p);

        return response.toString();
    }
```

On server side, I got NullPointerException when tried to get blobkey from the empty list.

My questions are: 
when HttpServletReqest(req) size is not null or zero?

Why "bstoreservice.getUploads(req)" return empty list? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I figure this out by myself, 'getUpload' return empty list because it failed to upload with byte array after changed to use FileBody, and everything is working fine.